# Automaing Power BI Report Generation

Tags: python, powerbi, data-analysis, build-automation

I have a power bi report that has a column known as Names. So, I want to automate the process of report generation. I want to write a script in python, such that I interact with the Power BI report,through the Power BI api and then create individual pdf for every name in the slicer, such that the person sees his own data.

I am not sure, how could i proceed with this problem. Any suggestion or recommendation is appreciated.

What I tried:
I have a python script, with which i am trying to access the Power Bi report. But, i keep getting a 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Assign User Roles in Power BI:
Power BI provides the feature of Row Level Security (RLS) that can be used to restrict data access for given users.
Create roles within Power BI and define rules to filter data based on the 'Names' column such that each role can only view data corresponding to a specific name.
Once the roles are set up, assign each user to the appropriate role based on their name.

Share Reports with Users:
Share the Power BI report with the users who have been assigned roles.
They would only be able to view data pertaining to their respective names due to the RLS settings.

Export Data as PDF through Power BI:
Users can then export their personalized view of the data as a PDF directly through Power BI.
This can be done by navigating to the File menu in Power BI and selecting Export to PDF.

By following this process, users will be able to see their own data and export it as a PDF without needing a Python script to automate report generation. This not only meets the requirement but also adheres to Power BI's built-in features for data security and report sharing, making the process more streamlined and manageable.